# Mongo db query formulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a database that has the following collection:

```
{id1: "1", id2: "a"}, {id1: "2", id2: "a"}, {id1: "3", id2: "a"}, {id1: "1", id2: "b"}, {id1: "2", id2: "b"}
```

I want to find `id2` given the list of `id1`: 1,2

the answer given should be `b` given that it is the only `id2` that has ONLY `1,2`

If the list of 'id1' given were: 1,2,3 then the 'id2' found should be 'a' given that 'a' is associated with 1,2 AND 3

How do I query this on *Mongodb* preferably using aggregation.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, and smells like homework

Comment: i explained the question further if you can help out that would be great

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  You can do it with an aggregate query, but it isn't very straight forward:

```
db.<collection_name>.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:"$id2",id1Set:{$addToSet:"$id1"}}},
    {$match:{"id1Set":{$size:2,$all:["1","2"]}}}
])
```

This query will group the documents by id2 and create a set containing the values of id1.  It then matches the documents from the group, looking at the size of the id1Set (should be 2) and the values in the id1Set should contain all of "1" and "2".

Since your example data contains string values for id2 ("1" and "2", rather than 1 and 2) the match is on string values rather than numbers.

Comment: Would I ever be able to use the ["1","2"] from a previous aggregation? I have the array found from a previous match ive made; however, when i put $all: "arrayName", it gives me the error "$all needs an array".. i dont have ["1", "2"] before i start the aggregation query

Comment: Maybe clearer if you ask a new question and provide the query you have created